# How to run tests one by one using Selenium and Python in one tab?

Tags: python, selenium, oop, automation, browser-automation

I am pretty new to automated testing, so do not beat me too hard.

So I have 2 separate files with 2 different tests:

1. Successful login
2. Creating a request

I can successfully run the Login case, but I can't run the second one, as it requires to be logged in. Is there any way I can run the 1-st one (User logs in) and run the next one in the same browser window without closing this window, so the next test was like a continuation of the previous one?

So, here is a test for Login

```
from selenium import webdriver

from pages.base_element import BaseElement
from pages.login_page import LoginPage

# Test Setup
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
currentURL = None

# Successful Login
log_page = LoginPage(driver=browser)
log_page.go()   <-------------------------------------------Goes to the Login Page                    
log_page.user_name_field.input_text('mail@gmail.com')

log_page.password_field.input_text('Pass123')
log_page.login_button.click()
```

And here is for creating a request

```
from selenium import webdriver
 
from pages.base_element import BaseElement 
from pages.med_page import LoginPage 
from pages.med_page import MedPage
 
# Test 
Setup browser = webdriver.Chrome() 
currentURL = None
 
# Test
med_page = MedPage(driver=browser) 
med_page.go()   <----------------- Must redirect to the Request Page, but redirects to Login as it is a new browser session, so the user is not logged in
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can! For this example, I will name your login code file as "login":

```
from login import *
from pages.med_page import MedPage


###some request###
```

When you reference the login script using "from login import *" it runs everything that is on the login script. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Yep, thank you! It made it much better! Now the tests are run one by one, but still in separate windows, so I can't create a request anyway https://www.screencast.com/t/urna3WtJ6cim

Comment: @Kiprian You should not have to initiate another driver in the ###some request### portion of your code. You should only need to call driver once then make your request. If you need to switch to suburl within that webpage then do so by saying "driver.get(subUrl)" You will only have to make "browser = webdriver.Chrome()" once.

Comment: @Kiprian If my answer helped you then please help me out by accepting my answer, thanks!!

Comment: Thank you @Luke so much! You really helped me!!!